# How to Suppress messages generated by an application being sent to my terminal window?

Tags: linux

When I launch an application from terminal related to the window system, for example gnome or kde, then usually these applications send all sorts of junk messages in my terminal. How do I make these applications shut up?

For example if I type:

```
 okular somepdf.pdf &
```

a window which shows the pdf file pops up and I can read the pdf next to my terminal, and when I am done I close.

Here is a typical example:

```
:~$ cd Documents
:~/Documents$ okular equi.dvi &
[1] 5823
```

and when I close it sends this junk to the terminal:

```
:~/Documents$ okular(5823)/kdeui (kdelibs) KXMLGUIClient::~KXMLGUIClient: 0x2322528 deleted without having been removed from the factory first. This will leak standalone popupmenus and could lead to crashes. 
d

d: command not found
[1]+  Done                    okular equi.dvi
[1]+  Done                    okular equi.dvi
:~/Documents$
```

The only thing I would like to see is:

```
:~$ cd Documents
:~/Documents$ okular equi.dvi &
:~/Documents$
```

Perhaps that message was some bug, I do not care and I do not want to know about it.

Is it possible to suppress these messages?

Some people flagged this question as a duplicate to a question on "how to suppress output", but this is only partially what I want:

I want to *automatically* suppress all output of certain applications. For instance okular is a graphical application, so I will never care about what it has to say in my terminal.

So like I said above, I want the behavior to be :

```
:~$ cd Documents
:~/Documents$ okular equi.dvi &
:~/Documents$
```

and *not* something like

```
:~$ cd Documents
:~/Documents$ okular equi.dvi > whatever &
:~/Documents$
```

Comment: The particular solution for KDE apps producing tons of junk is to run `kdebugdialog` and unselect all. Via http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/28vno2/til_stop_kde_apps_from_vomiting_all_over_your/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To suppress STDOUT:

```
yourcommand  1>/dev/null
```

To supress STDERR

```
yourcommand  2>/dev/null
```

Since bash 4 you can suppress both:

```
yourcommand &>/dev/null
```

You could also disable KDE's debug information with `kdedebugdialog` tool and disable output for selected modules (or all debug output).

Answer (score 2):

You can send the STDOUT and STDERR of the program to the dummy device `/dev/null`:

```
$ okular equi.dvi &> /dev/null &
```

To supress the job control messages, you can disable monitor mode in bash (maybe in your `.bashrc`):

```
$ set +m
```

I wouldn't recommend this, though. To enable it again, use `set -m`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress all text, just use the following command:

```
$> yourcommand >/dev/null &
```

If you also want to redirect stderr, you can do so like this:

```
$> yourcommand >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
okular equi.dvi > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

this will send all output (error messages and regular output) to `/dev/null`.