# How to change the output redirection of a running process?

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I know how to redirect output and how to [suppress them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33383/23363) in bash. Now, suppose I accidentally forgot to append the output redirection part to the command (e.g. `2>&1` or `> /tmp/mystdout`) and my background process is already running for a while, can I still change to where `stdout` and `stderr` are being written to? I really would like not to kill and restart the application.

To be more specific as asked by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) in his comment, I would like to fiddle with it in these scenarios in specific:

- wrong output file
- forgot to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`

or a combination of both

E.g. I have Apache running and I can *see* the file descriptors:

```
/proc/8019/fd/0 -> /dev/null
/proc/8019/fd/1 -> /dev/null
/proc/8019/fd/2 -> /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: Change to another terminal? Or to a file? If you're content with attaching to the current terminal or a new screen session, see [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using reredirect (https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/).

```
reredirect -m /dev/null <PID>
```

You can restore initial output of your process later using something like:

```
reredirect -N -O <M> -E <N> <PID>
```

(`<M>` and `<N>` are provided by previous launch of reredirect).

reredirect `README` also explains how to redirect to another command or to redirect only stdout or stderr.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. Or at least not easy. You might have some luck attaching gdb to the process and fiddling with it in gdb, but that can lead to crashes just as easily as success.

Comment: [There are tools for this nowadays](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034).

Comment: Feel free to share them, I'll upvote the answer :)

Comment: Um, [I already did](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell/4035#4035).

Comment: Not quite. All tools linked in the other bug are about attaching to another terminal/screen session. Not about redirecting to another file. Though it's probably not hard to patch reptyr to redirect to a file instead.

Comment: I've looked a bit into reptyr's source and I agree most with the "not easy" part of the answer. Might take a deeper dive into it some time later.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [reptyr](http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/) to attach another process to your new current terminal.
For example: install and use GNU's `screen` utility, and in it launch the `reptyr` command to "fetch" the other process's redirections (and controlling terminal) and attach them to the new current terminal (the `screen` process, if you launched `reptyr` from `screen`). The advantage of doing this from a `screen` session is that, once under `screen`, it will then be easy to disconnect and reconnect to it (for example, closing your local session, going home, and reopening it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help me with my case as I am not asking about terminal detach/retach. Please re-read my question and the example in specific.

Comment: ah, in that case : read the reptyr code, find out how to modify it to only redirect stdout or stderr. Then run it from another shell that redirects that newly-attached stream to where you want it to go? (or, better, using the reptyr source, do the redirection directly)