# Separate STDOUT noise from ncurses

Tags: terminal, io-redirection

I am trying to run an `ncurses` GUI application on an ARM board. I am running it using the serial console `ttyAMA0` port. But when I run the ncurses program, the other processes running in the background will print debug messages i.e qDebug, qWarning into `STDOUT` i.e on the GUI layout and hence results in noise. I think the problem is because all the processes are using the same console device.

So is there is a command line  or programmatic solution for this problem so that I could not see the other process' `STDOUT` on my `ncurses` GUI ?

I tried GNU `screen` It is not really helping. Even in screen session I am seeing the output of those processes polluting the screen

**P.S: I have tried [gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593764/829316) solution and it works fine. But I want alternative solution for this**

Comment: Possible duplicates and/or related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell/4035#4035 & http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59157/how-to-change-the-output-redirection-of-a-running-process

Answer (score 3):

I don't think what you want is possible. See this superuser thread titled: [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely).

I think you have essentially 3 options.

#### Option #1

Run the scripts that are polluting you terminal such that they're run like so:

```
nohup somescript &> /dev/null &
```

Which should run their STDOUT & STDIN to /dev/null, background them, and disconnect them from your terminal's signals if you should close it.

#### Option #2

Use something like `screen`. Thanks to @StephaneChazelas in the comments it does appear that there are [`screen` packages available for Debian on your architecture](http://packages.debian.org/search?arch=armel&keywords=screen).

#### Option #3

If you don't care if you temporarily pause the processes that are polluting your terminal's STDOUT you can use this setting: `stty tostop`. This has the effect of stopping these processes from sending their STDOUT to your terminal. When you're done you can re-enable it with the command `stty -nostop`. I found this in the [Unix Power Tools 3rd edition book](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch23_09.htm).

#### example

Here's my example app that is polluting my terminal's STDOUT:

```
$ while [ 1 ];do echo hi 2>&1;sleep 5;done &
```

This echoes out "hi" every 5 seconds like so:

```
[1] 30913
hi
$ hi
hi
hi
hi
```

Now when I run `stty tostop`:

```
$ stty tostop
$ date
Thu May  9 14:22:44 EDT 2013
$ date
Thu May  9 14:23:52 EDT 2013
```

The trouble with this approach is that the other process is stopped:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 while [ 1 ]; do
    echo hi 2>&1; sleep 5;
done
```

The trouble with this approach is that `stty -tostop` didn't resume the process, just the setting of my `stty` stating that STDOUT is allowed again. So I had to resume my process manually:

```
$ stty -tostop
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 while [ 1 ]; do
    echo hi 2>&1; sleep 5;
done

$ fg
while [ 1 ]; do
    echo hi 2>&1; sleep 5;
done
hi
^Z

[1]+  Stopped                 while [ 1 ]; do
    echo hi 2>&1; sleep 5;
done
$ bg
[1]+ while [ 1 ]; do
    echo hi 2>&1; sleep 5;
done &
$ hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

The above shows my running `stty -tostop`, then running the command `fg` to foreground the `while ...` process that was polluting my STDOUT, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, to stop the `while ...` process, then use the background command, `bg`.

**Additional Ideas**

Check out the suggestions tools on these U&L Q&As

- [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)
- [How to change the output redirection of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59157/how-to-change-the-output-redirection-of-a-running-process)

There are extensive lists of tools and possible paths for you to try out as alternatives to `screen`. Perhaps use `tmux` or reconnect the processes that are polluting your STDOUT to another terminal using [`reptyr`](http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/).

Comment: Option 1: Will not help as I dont have access to those polluting processes
Option 2: Have problems cross compiling `screen` for `ARM`

Comment: There are `screen`  packages for `arm` in Debian and probably most other distributions supporting arm.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Even `screen` command is not helping. I tried this I started a process in bg and then opened screen session. Even then in the new screen session I see the pollution

Comment: How did you launch the `screen` sessions? This can make a difference.