# redirecting output of running background job in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, background-process, output

in `bash` I have some jobs running, in background. They are always producing random irrelevant error messages that pollute the terminal. I am not always so prompt to start them with the `2>&1 > /dev/null` redirect. How can I redirect the output when they are *already* running?

Comment: See this related answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4035/74516 (not tested).

Comment: Thanks. Actually this command solved my problem in the most straightforward way: https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/

Comment: @fstab You can write that as an answer to your own question. I know I didn't know it was possible to do this (attaching to the target program as a debugger is quite a nice hack!), so I thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 12):

Bash can't modify the file descriptors of a running process.

See answers for [How to change the output redirection of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59157/how-to-change-the-output-redirection-of-a-running-process) (or a similar thread on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process))

The easiest and only current tool seems to be reredirect:

> [reredirect](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/) is a utility for taking an existing running program and attaching its outputs (standard output and error output) to files or another process. (quoting project homepage)

```
reredirect -m /dev/null <PID>
```