# Can I reclaim process foreground STDOUT after terminal loses network access?

Tags: centos, process, console, stdout

I am working in `CentOS 7.3` and I kicked off a couple of lengthy processes, unfortunately in the foreground. Then I went away from the terminal and was disconnected from my VPN due to inactivity. So I reestablished my connection and I can see the processes are still active and I get PIDs. Is there any way I can reclaim the process STDOUT if it was just printing to the console and not streamed into a file?

Comment: Probably not, and the worse news is when your lengthy processes write to stdout they will probably get signals which kill them.

Answer (score 2):

If the processes are still active and didn't get killed, you can use repytr or  [reredirect](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/) to attach them to a new terminal, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59157/how-to-change-the-output-redirection-of-a-running-process).

The way to avoid this problem is to use `screen` or `tmux` before you start processes on remote machines.