# Is it possible to stop output from a command after bg?

Tags: background-process, output

Suppose this situation

```
wget http://file
```

wget starts to download file.

I put it in the background.

```
^Z
bg
```

The command goes into the background.

But its output is still on the console also -- if the console is still open.

Is it possible to stop the command's output?

Wget is only an example; think about a command which writes a lot of output.

At the console, I know it is possible to do `bg` and then close terminal and open another, but what if I have only one terminal avaliable and no pseudo-terminals?

Comment: See [how to change the output redirection of a running process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59157/how-to-change-the-output-redirection-of-a-running-process). You can try reptyr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that actually redirects the output of a command *while* it is running: https://superuser.com/questions/732503/redirect-stdout-stderr-of-a-background-job-from-console-to-a-log-file

For a solution that is more usable in an every-day scenario of using a terminal, you could do
`wget -o log http://file &`
to run `wget` in the background and write its output to `log` instead of your terminal. Of course, you won't see any output at all in this case (even if you ran `wget` in foreground), but you could do `tail -f log` to look at the output as it grows.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean that you want to keep wget(or some other cmd) running background without outputing messages to the console? If that's the question, you can try `redirection`

```
$ wget http://file > /dev/null
```

the cmd above will redirect the `stdout` to `/dev/null` and you won't see messages except error messages.
If you don't want to see error messages either, try this

```
$ wget http://file 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

You can google `redirection` for more detailed information.